# Trying to understand valgrind output

Tags: c++, qt, valgrind

Here is the valgrind output..

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
in RingsWidget::UpdateSeekBar() in ringswidget.cpp:514
1: RingsWidget::UpdateSeekBar() in <a href="file:///media/dipesh/Documents/Qt-projects/NomadDesktop-build-Desktop-Debug/../NomadDesktop/ringswidget.cpp:514" >ringswidget.cpp:514</a>
2: RingsWidget::UpdateRings() in <a href="file:///media/dipesh/Documents/Qt-projects/NomadDesktop-build-Desktop-Debug/../NomadDesktop/ringswidget.cpp:138" >ringswidget.cpp:138</a>
3: RingsWidget::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) in <a href="file:///media/dipesh/Documents/Qt-projects/NomadDesktop-build-Desktop-Debug/moc_ringswidget.cpp:49" >/media/dipesh/Documents/Qt-projects/NomadDesktop-build-Desktop-Debug/moc_ringswidget.cpp:49</a>
4: QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) in /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.4
5: QObject::event(QEvent*) in /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.4
6: QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) in /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4.8.4
7: QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) in /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4.8.4
8: QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) in /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.4
9: /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.4
10: /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.4
11: g_main_context_dispatch in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.3400.3
12: /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.3400.3
13: g_main_context_iteration in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.3400.3
14: QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags&lt;QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag&gt;) in /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.4
15: /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4.8.4
16: QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags&lt;QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag&gt;) in /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.4
17: QEventLoop::exec(QFlags&lt;QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag&gt;) in /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.4
18: QCoreApplication::exec() in /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.4
19: main in <a href="file:///media/dipesh/Documents/Qt-projects/NomadDesktop-build-Desktop-Debug/../NomadDesktop/main.cpp:19" >main.cpp:19</a>

Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation  1: operator new(unsigned long) in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
2: MusicWidget::MusicWidget(QWidget*) in <a href="file:///media/dipesh/Documents/Qt-projects/NomadDesktop-build-Desktop-Debug/../NomadDesktop/musicwidget.cpp:148" >musicwidget.cpp:148</a>
3: NomadWindow::Initialize() in <a href="file:///media/dipesh/Documents/Qt-projects/NomadDesktop-build-Desktop-Debug/../NomadDesktop/nomadwindow.cpp:127" >nomadwindow.cpp:127</a>
4: NomadWindow::NomadWindow(QWidget*) in <a href="file:///media/dipesh/Documents/Qt-projects/NomadDesktop-build-Desktop-Debug/../NomadDesktop/nomadwindow.cpp:27" >nomadwindow.cpp:27</a>
5: main in <a href="file:///media/dipesh/Documents/Qt-projects/NomadDesktop-build-Desktop-Debug/../NomadDesktop/main.cpp:15" >main.cpp:15</a>
```

Here is the code..

```
511 NomadWindow *par = (NomadWindow*)parent();
512 float percentage = par->GetMusicWidget()->GetMPDSeekPerc();
513 settings[5].operator []("value") = percentage;
514 if ( percentage < 0.2 )
515     settings[5].operator []("fg_alpha") = 0.2;
516 else
517     settings[5].operator []("fg_alpha") = percentage;
```

The valgrind output is from the line 514
    if ( percentage < 0.2 )

What is it that i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if valgrind propagates the use of the uninitialized value accessed in `GetMPDSeekPerc()` and reports an error when the uninitialized value is actually used for something rather than than just passing it along. The message about `Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation ...` quite bluntly points to where the uninitialized value is coming from.

Comment: Turns out the percentage variable from the getMPDSeekPerc() may not have a value all the time. I initialiazed the variable to zero in the constructor and the valgrind stopped complaining. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

This means in general that you have an if that tests a value that is not initialized. The result of the if is therefore random.

To go further you need to know where this variable is allocated/declared. You can get this information from :

> Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation  1: operator new(unsigned long) in ...
>   MusicWidget::MusicWidget(QWidget*) in [...] musicwidget.cpp:148

That means that in musicwidget.cpp, line 148, you make a new on a int (the percentage) but you don't initialize it. You should find you error there.

Off topic: using new on an int usually not a good idea. Rather declare it as a variable if possible

Comment: I'm not using new on an int. This is what i have in musicwidget.cpp
    145 zekton_font = new QFont("Zekton");
    146 inconsolata_font = new QFont("Inconsolata");
    147
    148 client = new NomadMPD(this);
    149 client->Connect();

Comment: It can be Qt that does the allocation. Can you give the code around line 148 of musicwidget.cpp ?

Comment: `145 zekton_font = new QFont("Zekton");

146 inconsolata_font = new QFont("Inconsolata");`
`147 `
`148 client = new NomadMPD(this);`
`149 client->Connect();`
from musicwidget.cpp

Comment: Thanks, so I guess that NomadMPD contains the percentage that is returned ?

Comment: Yes. I figured out the problem. Turns out the percentage variable may not have a value all the time. I initialiazed the variable to zero in NomadMPD constructor and the valgrind stopped complaining. Thanks for the help.